# Elasticsearch native or elasticsearch-odm

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, content-management-system

I'm preparing to build a application (CMS) using ElasticSearch on Nodejs backend.
I'm choosing between elasticsearch native from ES and elasticsearch-odm from npm. 
I'm test some example with CURL, Kibana RESTful API and see it simple to useful.
My system used Mongooese for other collections so i wonder if elasticsearch-odm reasonable proposal if it support same...
I am total new in this field, near realtime search as ES. 
Please give me any infomation . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your question?

1: Run ES standalone or as part of the application?
It's better to run Elasticsearch standalone. You won't start ES every time when you start your application. Startingup ES can can take some time (starting, syncing; takes longer when you have a lot of data).

2: Is ES a good replacement for MongoDB?
Depends on your requirement. Elasticsearch is for SEARCH. Don't use is as (primary) database. Elasticsearch is not transactional! (there are more reasons why you won't do that)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I just wonder about using native lib or other lib for ES